# table users_data has no column named

Tags: android

i am new in this android stuido programing and i hope that you will 
     help me with this problem. I know that you answered this question before 
     but all methodes that you show doest help me. I have database that when i 
     want to add something it shows error that there is no column named in my 
     data base. If you can help me i would be very appreciate.

```
 enter code here package algebra.hr.order;

 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

 public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Order2.db";
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users_data";
 public static final String COL1 = "ID";
 public static final String COL2 = "broj";
 public static final String COL3 = "hrana";
 public static final String COL4 = "piče";
 public static final String COL5 = "vrijeme";


 public DataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 3);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2  + "TEXT, " + COL3 + "TEXT, " + COL4 + "TEXT, " + COL5 + 
 "TEXT"
             + ");";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
 }

  public boolean addData(String broj, String hrana, String piče , String 
 vrijeme) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, broj);
    contentValues.put(COL3, hrana);
    contentValues.put(COL4, piče);
    contentValues.put(COL5 , vrijeme);

    float result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);


    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }


   public Cursor getListContents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME,  null);
    return data;
  }

  }





enter code here package algebra.hr.order;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Spinner hrana , piće;
 EditText soba;
 Button btn1, btn2;
 String HRANA = "";
 String PIČE = "";
 String broj ="";
 String vrijeme = "";
 Date d;
 DataBase db;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main2 );

    hrana = (Spinner)findViewById ( R.id.Odabirhrane );
    piće = (Spinner)findViewById ( R.id.Odabirpića );
    soba = (EditText)findViewById ( R.id.brojSobe );
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById ( R.id.btnNatuci );
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById ( R.id.povjest );




    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource ( 
     this , R.array.Hrana, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
    hrana.setAdapter ( adapter );

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource ( 
    this, R.array.Pića , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    piće.setAdapter ( adapter1 );

    btn1.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            broj = soba.getText ().toString ();
            HRANA = hrana.getSelectedItem ().toString ();
            PIČE = piće.getSelectedItem ().toString ();
            db = new DataBase ( Main2Activity.this );
            d = new Date (  );
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ( "hh:mm a" );
            vrijeme = sdf.format ( d );
            if (broj.length () != 0 && HRANA.length () != 0 && PIČE.length 
  () != 0 && vrijeme.length () != 0) {
                adddata ( broj , HRANA , PIČE , vrijeme );
            } else {
                Toast.makeText ( Main2Activity.this , "Niste ništa naručili" 
   , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();

            }
        }
    } );
    btn2.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent  i = new Intent ( Main2Activity.this , DataView.class );
            startActivity ( i );
        }
    } );



  }
  public void adddata( String b , String h ,String p ,String v){
    boolean insertData = db.addData ( b , h , p , v);
    if(insertData==true){
        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Uspješno ste 
  naručili.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Nešto je pošlo po zlu : 
   (.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

   }
   }
```

Comment: Give the full error please.....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need add space in data type in oncreate your sqlite like this

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2  + " TEXT, " + COL3 + " TEXT, " + COL4 + " TEXT, " + COL5 + 
 " TEXT"
             + ");";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
 }
```